# I want to take profit using take profit in points. Points are counted even for lost trades and I want points to count for only profits

Tags: mql4, mql5

I want to take profit using take profit in points. Points are counted even for lost trades and I want points to count for only profits. Need help

I tried to let only profit points count and when trade closes and is a lost trade, profit points will not add the lost trade points to the total profit points needed to close a trade in profit but I am unable to achieve this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.